# Вывод категорий из базы данных в цикле

Tags: php, циклы, mysql

Выходит ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH

вот код

```
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) {
    exit(mysql_error());    }

   $row = array()
    foreach($i = 0;< mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);     
     printf("<li><a href='#'>%s</a></li>", $row['title']);
     }
      ?>
```

Comment: Точку с запятой забыли поставить после `$row = array()`

Comment: @wandomfayv, для таких целей используйте [while][1], а не foreach. Вы работаете не с массивом, а с результирующим набором, хоть и массивоподобным. И использование расширения **mysql_*** не рекомендуется ([читаем выделенное красным][2])!

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT *
                         FROM category');
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $mas[$i]['id']=$row->id ;
        $mas[$i]['title']=$row->title;
$i++;
}
print_r($mas);
```

foreach ($mas as $value){
echo '<li><a href="#">%s</a></li>'.$value['title'].';
}

Comment: А не проще ли будет так:

    $mas = array();
    while (...) {
        $mas[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'title' => $row->title,
        );
    }

И на будущее: переменным лучше давать осмысленные имена. `$mas` - вроде и массив, а что за массив не ясно. Приходится смотреть код выше/ниже, чтобы понять его назначение. Аналогично с `$value`